# Thermal diffusity. What do I use?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, estimation, flow, thermal-conductivity

I'm not a physics expert. Actually don't know much at all but I'm trying to find an answer to a problem.

> If I had a silicone (or clear vinyl if more appropriate) tube with .25 inch interior diameter and .375 exterior diameter and about 50ft long with 500 ml of a liquid inside it with 20 stainless steel u turns (could be a different metal if it matters), what would be the best liquid to put into the tube to remove heat at a faster pace and store it as it crosses a heated surface but then can dump the heat quickly onto a cooler surface?

Tube length/diameter is variable and approximate and temperatures are rough. Assume flow rate of 1/lpm

For example tubing crosses a 50c or 122f surface. It runs 25ft or about 8m collecting heat. Then tubing passes into a cooler environment for about 1m or 3ft (for example 40c or around 90f) and must distribute all collected heat there. I thought about pulling a vacuum on the cooling area to boil water and make the gas easier to cool quickly but had so many issues with size and weight among other things that idea was placed on a side burner for now.

Comment: The dimensions and material of the tube would not matter much. The fluid you choose should have high specific heat capacity. Hence distilled water should do you just fine.

Comment: I tried that,it couldn't drop the heat it obtained and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant equations are (Heat equation)$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha\left(\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial z^2}\right)$$
and (fouriers law)$$ \mathbf{q} = - k {\nabla} T$$
Thus you can see the thermal conductivity(k) tells us how much heat is transferred for a given temperature difference across some length where as the thermal diffusivity(alpha) tells us how fast the temperature of the heat transfer fluid will increase.
Since you want fast heat transfer you want a fluid with a large thermal conductivity. If you also want the temperature of the fluid to be low you want it to have a large conductivity but a small diffusivity.

Comment: If I had a small diffusity wouldn't it be difficult to remove the collected heat? Fo instance, if I collect 122f or 50C heat over 1 minute, would I be able to remove that heat in 10 seconds over the cold plates? Assuming the cold plates were at 100f or 43C (basically a 20f Delta T). Im thinking I need a liquid that becomes a gas just prior to passing through the cooling area so I'm able to remove as much heat as possible.  Am I explaining this correctly?